# Display current month values based upon abbreviation (Oct) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

I am currently dealing with a table that looks like this:

```
PersonID    Month
    1       Dec
    2       Jan
    3       Oct
    4       Oct
    5       Jan
    6       Feb
```

I want to select rows where the month is equal to today's month. So for example for this current month i want all the rows that are equal to October but obviously this appears as 'Oct'. Is there anyway i can achieve this?

Desired output

```
PersonID    Month
    3       Oct
    4       Oct
```

I thought maybe something along the lines of

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN Month = 'Oct'
THEN '01-10-17'
ELSE 'N/A' END AS [Date]

FROM Person

WHERE Month([Date]) = Month(getdate())
```

But im not sure this logic is that solid.

SQL - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3f33/1

Comment: @Tanner no, i dont want it in a 3 letter abbreviation. I want to select the values based on the current month

Comment: and all of the code required is on the linked post in some form, you just need to add it to your where clause.

Comment: @Tanner its not a duplicate of that question though

Comment: You might not see it as an exact duplicate, but anyone with basic SQL knowledge should be able to see how you can get the answer you need from the duplicate suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMM') = Month;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LNQVM10932)**

Remarks:

- SQL Server 2012 and above
- language for session should be English: [`SET LANGUAGE English;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Another option if not 2012+.

```
Select left(datename(MONTH,getdate()),3)
```

Returns

```
Oct
```

So for your actual query

```
Select *
  From  Person
  Where Month = left(datename(MONTH,getdate()),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do it with CONVERT:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE Month = Convert(char(3), GetDate(), 0)
```